# Determine calling application GUID

Tags: dll, guid

I want to add a form of access security to a DLL that I created and I was hoping to restrict within the code a check of the calling application's GUID.  I cannot seem to find a way to retrieve the calling app's GUID to verify if it has access.

Is this even possible, and if so could someone provide a code snippet on how to determine the GUID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer...here is an example in VB:

```
    Dim asm As Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    Dim attribs = (asm.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(GuidAttribute), True))
    MsgBox(DirectCast(attribs(0), GuidAttribute).Value.ToUpper)
```

This provides the calling application's GUID.